# Uncaught ReferenceError: saveAttribute is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, php, magento

For the longest time I had no issues with adding or editing attributes. Starting yesterday 04/10/2017 I ran into an issue that the Save & Save and Continue button will absolutely not work. It works for every other part of the admin side of things but not the attributes. When I click the buttons I get the error in the title on the chrome developers tool console.

I looked through the files and as far as I can see everything is the same since I installed Magento. So, I am at a loss for trying to figure out how to fix this issue. If somebody could let me know of a possible way to get this worked out that would be amazing.

Thank You,

Michael

EDIT:

This is located in the js.phtml file.

```
function saveAndContinueEdit(){
disableElements('save');
var activeTab = product_attribute_tabsJsTabs.activeTab.id;
if (editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/tab/' + activeTab) == false) {
    enableElements('save');
 }
varienGlobalEvents.attachEventHandler('formValidateAjaxComplete', function (){
    enableElements('save');
});}

function saveAttribute(){
disableElements('save');
if (editForm.submit() == false){
    enableElements('save');
}
varienGlobalEvents.attachEventHandler('formValidateAjaxComplete', function (){
    enableElements('save');
});}
```

Comment: Looks like `saveAttribute` function disappear from global scope

Comment: the error is pretty vague, there are a couple of reason why you will be having such error in the console. If you know your code, you should be trying checking it and post it here and briefly explain how it is being process